# Java Control Panel does not show installed java runtime

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, java

I installed the Java 8 64bit runtime in parallel to a Java 7 64bit runtime on my Windows 7 machine.

Now the Java Control Panel does not list any runtime in the tab "Java" any more. Specifically, the "View..." button in the "Java" tab is greyed out.

- I already uninstalled all java runtimes, and reinstalled only the Java 8 runtime.
- I also started the Java Control Panel directly from the directory of the jre, to ensure that I'm not using an old vetrsion of the control panel.
- I already found out that the list of JRE is generated from information in the registry. There is an entry HLM->Software->JavaSoft->Java Runtime Environment->1.8.0_25 that looks good. Just to be sure, I deleted the complete JavaSoft key before reinstalling the JRE

I want to change the default options of the JRE, which is possible in the "View..." dialog.

How can I make the Control Panal aware of my JRE?

Alternatively, is there another way to specify the default option for a jre?

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the users Appdata and delete the Sun folder from the Roaming and the LocalLow folders.

It will then correctly show the View button enabled.

Comment: This did not work for me.